# Magento 2 - after upgrading EC2 instance Magento crashes during every product save with CPU at 100%

Tags: magento2, product, apache2

I have a site in development using Magento (2.2.5) on a EC2 instance with only one CPU and everything was working fine. I then upgraded the EC2 instance to 4 CPUs (standard instance upgrade on AWS) for production. Suddenly every time I save a product on the backend (simple and basic product with no options) the server crashes as Apache takes 100% of the CPU (as witnessed with the "top" command).

What can be causing this issue? All that happened was the server was stopped, upgraded and restarted.

I have tried restarting mysql, apache, varnish and cronjobs but nothing helped. I have also flushed the cache and reindexed.

What can be causing this issue?

Please help.

Comment: Please post your error log and complete my.cnf for analysis.

Comment: Are you running now or still need assistance?  If you need assistance, please post your complete error log and my.cnf or my.ini for analysis.  If you could post TEXT results of A) top  B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%;  and C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%';  D) how much RAM on your server?   Suggestions will be offered to consider.

Comment: Please post information requested Jul 20, 2018 for assistance.